# Unable to run a job with OutputTags

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I've been struggling with a job that needs to emit side outputs, as I keep getting an exception ('unable to serialize xxx').

Even though I explicitly specified a coder for the type I am working with, I kept getting the same error, so I decided to write a simple job following this documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do#tags-for-side-outputs

To my surprise, I still get the same kind of an exception, and now I suspect that I must have done something wrong (but I can't really figure it out myself). As far as the code is concerned, I tried to follow the example given above.

Below, I am posting source code as well as error message I get when I run it. I believe this is reproducible (change the 'GCS_BUCKET' to any bucket you own, and create main() method that calls 'TestSideOutput' with args), and it will be good to know if someone else can reproduce on their end.
We are using JDK 8 and Dataflow SDK 1.7.0.

Please note that the example in the documentation above uses an anonymous class extending DoFn, which I also tried but got the same kind of error message; the code below refactors this class into a named inner-class ('Filter') instead.

I also tried initializing TupleTags without the curly braces ("{}") -- because this actually yields warning -- which lead to an exception (see the last code snippet in this post).

Here is the code I used:

```
package tmp.dataflow.experimental;

import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.StringUtf8Coder;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.TextIO;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.PCollection;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.PCollectionTuple;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.TupleTag;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.TupleTagList;
import com.moloco.dataflow.DataflowConstants;

public class TestSideOutput {
  private TestOptions options;
  private static final String GCS_BUCKET = "gs://dataflow-experimental/"; // Change to your bucket name

  public TestSideOutput(String[] args) {
    options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).as(TestOptions.class);
    options.setProject(DataflowConstants.PROJCET_NAME);
    options.setStagingLocation(DataflowConstants.STAGING_BUCKET);
    options.setRunner(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.class);
    options.setJobName(options.getJob() + "-test-sideoutput");
  }

  public void execute() {
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
    // 1. Read sample data.
    PCollection<String> profiles = pipeline.apply(TextIO.Read.named("reading")
        .from(GCS_BUCKET + "example/sample-data/sample-data*").withCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of()));

    // 2. Create tags for outputs.
    final TupleTag<String> mainTag = new TupleTag<String>() {};
    final TupleTag<String> sideTag = new TupleTag<String>() {};

    // 3. Apply ParDo with side output tags.
    Filter filter = new Filter("DATAFLOW", sideTag);
    PCollectionTuple results =
        profiles.apply(ParDo.named("FilterByKeyword").withOutputTags(mainTag, TupleTagList.of(sideTag)).of(filter));

    // 4. Retrieve outputs.
    PCollection<String> mainOutput = results.get(mainTag);
    PCollection<String> sideOutput = results.get(sideTag);

    // 5. Write to GCS.
    mainOutput.apply(
        TextIO.Write.named("writingMain").to(GCS_BUCKET + "example/main-output/main").withCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of()));
    sideOutput.apply(
        TextIO.Write.named("writingSide").to(GCS_BUCKET + "example/side-output/side").withCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of()));

    // 6. Run pipeline.
    pipeline.run();
  }

  static class Filter extends DoFn<String, String> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0;
    final TupleTag<String> sideTag;
    String keyword;

    public Filter(String keyword, TupleTag<String> sideTag) {
      this.sideTag = sideTag;
      this.keyword = keyword;
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
      String profile = c.element();
      if (profile.contains(keyword)) {
        c.output(profile);
      } else {
        c.sideOutput(sideTag, profile);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the command I used, and the error/exception I got (it just contains a few command-line arguments we use for our dataflow package, nothing special here, but just to give you an idea):

```
dataflow-20161003.R3$ ./bin/dataflow --job=test-experimental-sideoutput --numWorkers=1 --date=0001-01-01
Oct 04, 2016 12:37:34 AM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner fromOptions
INFO: PipelineOptions.filesToStage was not specified. Defaulting to files from the classpath: will stage 121 files. Enable logging at DEBUG level to see which files will be staged.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to serialize tmp.dataflow.experimental.TestSideOutput$Filter@6986852
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.serializeToByteArray(SerializableUtils.java:54)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.clone(SerializableUtils.java:91)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.ParDo$BoundMulti.<init>(ParDo.java:959)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.ParDo$UnboundMulti.of(ParDo.java:912)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.ParDo$UnboundMulti.of(ParDo.java:908)
        at tmp.dataflow.experimental.TestSideOutput.execute(TestSideOutput.java:41)
        at com.moloco.dataflow.Main.main(Main.java:152)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: tmp.dataflow.experimental.TestSideOutput
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.serializeToByteArray(SerializableUtils.java:50)
        ... 6 more
```

In addition, I don't think this is relevant, but the code for the 'TestOptions' class:

```
package tmp.dataflow.experimental;

import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.DataflowPipelineOptions;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.Description;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.Validation;

public interface TestOptions extends DataflowPipelineOptions {
  @Description("Job")
  @Validation.Required
  String getJob();

  void setJob(String value);

  @Description("Job suffix")
  String getJobSuffix();

  void setJobSuffix(String value);

  @Description("Date")
  @Validation.Required
  String getDate();

  void setDate(String value);
}
```

Lastly, if I were to remove the curly brackets "{}" when instantiating TupleTags, I would get the following exception instead (and I found suggestions on Stackoverflow that I should instantisate them with "{}" to avoid this kind of issue):

```
Oct 04, 2016 12:43:56 AM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner fromOptions
INFO: PipelineOptions.filesToStage was not specified. Defaulting to files from the classpath: will stage 122 files. Enable logging at DEBUG level to see which files will be staged.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to return a default Coder for FilterByKeyword.out1 [PCollection]. Correct one of the following root causes:
  No Coder has been manually specified;  you may do so using .setCoder().
  Inferring a Coder from the CoderRegistry failed: Cannot provide a coder for type variable V (declared by class com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.TupleTag) because the actual type is unknown due to erasure. If this error occurs for a side output of the producing ParDo, verify that the TupleTag for this output is constructed with proper type information (see TupleTag Javadoc) or explicitly set the Coder to use if this is not possible.
  Using the default output Coder from the producing PTransform failed: Cannot provide a coder for type variable V (declared by class com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.TupleTag) because the actual type is unknown due to erasure.
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.TypedPValue.inferCoderOrFail(TypedPValue.java:195)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.TypedPValue.getCoder(TypedPValue.java:48)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.PCollection.getCoder(PCollection.java:137)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.TypedPValue.finishSpecifying(TypedPValue.java:88)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:331)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:274)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:161)
        at tmp.dataflow.experimental.TestSideOutput.execute(TestSideOutput.java:50)
        at com.moloco.dataflow.Main.main(Main.java:152)
```

---

Edit: See the answer below for resolving this by making execute() 'static'.

The code below resembles what I originally posted, with two changes:
Whenever possible, I specify explicitly (and redundantly) 'coder' again for each PCollection. In addition, when instantiating TupleTags, no curly braces.

Note sure which approach (static vs this redundant approach) is more appropriate.

```
  public void execute() {
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
    // 1. Read sample data.
    PCollection<String> profiles = pipeline.apply(TextIO.Read.named("reading")
        .from(GCS_BUCKET + "example/sample-data/sample-data*").withCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of()));

    // 2. Create tags for outputs.
    final TupleTag<String> mainTag = new TupleTag<String>();
    final TupleTag<String> sideTag = new TupleTag<String>();

    // 3. Apply ParDo with side output tags.
    Filter filter = new Filter("DATAFLOW", sideTag);
    PCollectionTuple results = profiles.setCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
        .apply(ParDo.named("FilterByKeyword").withOutputTags(mainTag, TupleTagList.of(sideTag)).of(filter));

    // 4. Retrieve outputs.
    PCollection<String> mainOutput = results.get(mainTag);
    PCollection<String> sideOutput = results.get(sideTag);

    // 5. Write to GCS.
    mainOutput.setCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of()).apply(TextIO.Write.named("writingMain")
        .to(GCS_BUCKET + "example/main-output-from-nonstatic/main").withCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of()));
    sideOutput.setCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of()).apply(TextIO.Write.named("writingSide")
        .to(GCS_BUCKET + "example/side-output-from-nonstatic/side").withCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of()));

    // 6. Run pipeline.
    pipeline.run();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is because your `Filter` fn references the `TupleTag`, which in turn (because it's a non-static anonymous class instantiated from a non-static function `execute()`) references the enclosing `TestSideOutput`.

So the pipeline is trying to serialize the `TestSideOutput` object, and it is not serializable - as evidenced by the message: `java.io.NotSerializableException: tmp.dataflow.experimental.TestSideOutput`.

The root cause is that the method `execute()` is not static. Making it static should fix the issue.

Comment: Indeed, what yo suggested fixed the problem I was having. Thank you!

On the other hand, we have another job which has a non-static execute() method from which we apply ParDo with side output tags, and it does not throw an exception (and that is partly why I wrote the sample code above, as it seemed strange to me). I can't really post that cost at this time, but I am wondering if there is another way to fix this problem without making the execute() method static?

Comment: I kinda answered my follow-up question (see the added code snippet at the end of my edited question).  It appears possible to keep execute() as non-static, by explicitly and redundantly declaring coders whenever possible.